# NativeScript ListView. Get position of first visible item iOS

Tags: ios, listview, nativescript

Please, help. How I get first visible item position on iOS?

for Android, I have this code, and it works

```
restListing.android.getFirstVisiblePosition()
```

Answer (score 1):

NativeScript's ListView is using [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/visibleCells) in iOS.
Maybe something like this can be useful for your case :

```
var list = <ListView>page.getViewById("list");
var visibleCells = list.ios.visibleCells;
console.log(visibleCells);
console.log(visibleCells[0]); // first visible cell
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending on [Nick's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786676/10391569), the following code would return the same type as the android counterpart does.

```js
/**
 * Get first visible item from a ListView instance.
 *
 * @returns first visible item (platform agnostic).
 * @param listView {N} ListView instance.
 */
function firstVisibleItemIndexFromListView(listView: ListView): number {
  if (isAndroid) return listView.android.getFirstVisiblePosition();

  // Feel free to remove the UITableView casting, it works either way.
  // This just allows for type-checking and type-hinting!
  const tableView = listView.ios as UITableView;
  const visibleIndexes = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows;
  return visibleIndexes[0].row;
}
```

I hope this helps new NativeScript developers!